# What is curses.COLORS in Python curses library?

Tags: python, python-curses

I would like to know what `curses.COLORS` is in the `curses` module.
I didn't find any explanation on what exactly it is in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

Answer (score 0):

From what I figured out it is something like the max number of colors your terminal supports. Didn't look any closer.